# How to store and query the raw text?

Tags: pallet, storage

I want to query the task from storage. Here is the Task struct and StorageMap

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen, Default)]
    #[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
    pub struct Task<T:Config>{
        pub id: [u8; 16],
        pub state: u8,
        pub owner: T::AccountId,
        pub description: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<100>>,
        // pub deadline
    }

#[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn gettasks)]
    pub(super) type Tasks<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, [u8; 16], Task<T>>;
```

when creating task, I enter "Hi" for the field description. But when query by taskId, It shows

```
{"id":"0x....","state":1,"owner":"5Grw...","description":"0x6869"}
```

How to make the description showing in raw text?

Answer (score 0):

Substrate runtimes use `u8` data for strings, whereas Rust normally uses `String`.

You can convert it back from raw like this:

```rust
// Some description queried from storage.
let description: [u8; 16] = [0x68, 0x69, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                             0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00];

match String::from_utf8(description.to_vec()) {
    Ok(s) => println!("{}", s),
    Err(e) => println!("Error: {}", e),
}
// prints 'hi'
```

Note that this will not work *within* the runtime code, since it cannot use strings.